# Issues with changing the state of a single <input> tag in a mapped array without affecting other instances in Next.js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I am creating a simple web app game and trying to implement a 'grading' feature. When the correct answer is typed in the `<input>` changes styles. There are a different number of possible answers based on the question's prompt. To display the right number of `<input>` for each question prompt I am using `array.map()`. My issue is that when I change the state of a single `<input>` the state changes for all of them. How can I change the state of just a single `<input>` in a mapped array?

```
const CountryList = ({countries, firstLetter}) => {
  const [answer, checkAnswer] = useState(false);

  const handleAnswer = useDebouncedCallback((e) => {
    const value = e.target.value;
    if (value) {
      if (value.length > 4 && countries.includes(value)) {
        checkAnswer(true);
      }
    } else if (!value) {
        checkAnswer(false);
    }
  }, 300);

  if (firstLetter == '' || firstLetter == ' '){
    return (
      <div className={styles.container}>
        
      </div>
    )
  } else {
    return (
      <div className={styles.container}>
        <div className={styles.numbox}>
          <h3 className={styles.countrynum}>
            {`There are ${countries.length} countries that start with '${firstLetter.toUpperCase()}'`}
          </h3>
        </div>
        <div className={styles.answerbox}>
          {countries.map((country, index, thisValue) => (
                <input key={country} 
                       id={`answer-${index}`}
                       className={`${answer? styles.answercorrect : styles.answer}`}
                       onChange={handleAnswer} >
                </input>
          ))}
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

I have tried passing `this` but have been unsuccessful. I believe it may have to do with how I am calling `useDebounceCallback()` but I am unsure.

Comment: There is only one state for all of the inputs, so when one changes, they all change. Make the input a separate component so that each input can have its own state. I'd also suggest passing whether the answer is correct via a prop. Then use your custom input component in the map.